# Вроде решил задачу, но приложение ее не принимает

Tags: javascript

Задача:

> "Вы создаете шифратор текста, он должен использовать несколько слов  и вывести в результат скомбинированную версию, где каждое слово отделено знаком $.
> Например, для слов "hello", "how", "are", "you", результат должен выглядеть следующим образом: "$hello$how$are$you$".
> Данный код объявляет класс Add, с конструктором, который берет один rest параметр.
> Завершите код, добавив к классу метод print(), который должен создать необходимый результат."

Я ее сделал следующим образом, однако программа ругается, что код неверен. Почему?

Вот код:

```js
class Add{//исходно дано в задаче
    constructor(...words){//исходно дано в задаче
        this.words = words;//исходно дано в задаче
    }//исходно дано в задаче
    print(){ //создал метод print, как условлено в задаче
        var str = this.words.join("$");//сделал переменную, которая выведет новый массив с $ вместо запятых
        var b = "$"+str+"$"; //новая переменная, что прибавит вначале и в конце массива по знаку, как надо
        console.log(b);// вывод этой задачи. И как я проверяю, все работает 
    }
}
var x = new Add("hehe", "hoho", "haha"); //исходно дано в задаче
var y = new Add("this", "is", "awesome");//исходно дано в задаче
var z = new Add("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", ",", "sit");//исходно дано в задаче
x.print();//исходно дано в задаче
y.print();//исходно дано в задаче
z.print();//исходно дано в задаче
```

Comment: Возможно, еще надо очистить массив от пустых значений?

Comment: говорит то отделять слова, а вы вот и знаки препинания выделяете. не понятно, что с ними делать, мб вообще пропускать.

Comment: помимо этого, вроде указано. что метод должен вернуть результат,а не вывести его в консоль

Comment: @teran, можешь подсказать как мне надо решить задачу? Я так и не понял, где я ошибаюсь. Я же вывожу все правильно, выводится всё слитно через знак $ и он есть вначале и в конце, что не так?  И еще, вернуть его надо через return? Так тоже делал, не получилось.

Comment: Я решил эту задачу следущим образом, надеюсь поможет! Удачи
![решение]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrapm.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, не надо было отправлять результат с запятой и прочими "не словами".

```js
class Add{//исходно дано в задаче
    constructor(...words){//исходно дано в задаче
        this.words = words;//исходно дано в задаче
    }//исходно дано в задаче
    print(){ //создал метод print, как условлено в задаче
        var str = this.words.filter((value)=>/^[a-z]+$/i.test(value)).join("$");//сделал переменную, которая выведет новый массив с $ вместо запятых
        var b = "$"+str+"$"; //новая переменная, что прибавит вначале и в конце массива по знаку, как надо
        console.log(b);// вывод этой задачи. И как я проверяю, все работает 
    }
}
var x = new Add("hehe", "hoho", "haha"); //исходно дано в задаче
var y = new Add("this", "is", "awesome");//исходно дано в задаче
var z = new Add("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", ",", "sit");//исходно дано в задаче
x.print();//исходно дано в задаче
y.print();//исходно дано в задаче
z.print();//исходно дано в задаче
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все решено. Но я не понял, как ты это сделал...

Comment: [Регулярные выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) и [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) и [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)